# sending email by JSP code

Tags: jsp

I have a JSP code. I try to send an smtp email by that. It has an error in:

Transport.send(message); .

Can anybody help me?

here is the code:

```
 <%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,javax.mail.*, javax.mail.Service"%>
 <%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.*,javax.activation.*"%>
 <%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
 <%
 String result;
 // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
 String to = "email@gmx.com";

 // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
 String from = "email@gmx.com";

 // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
 String host = "mail.gmx.com";

 // Get system properties object
 Properties properties = System.getProperties();

 // Setup mail server
 properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

 // Get the default Session object.
 Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);


  // Create a default MimeMessage object.
  MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
  // Set From: header field of the header.
  message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
  // Set To: header field of the header.
  message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                           new InternetAddress(to));
  // Set Subject: header field
  message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");
  // Now set the actual message
  message.setText("This is actual message");
  // Send message
  Transport.send(message);
  result = "Sent message successfully....";

%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Send Email using JSP</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>Send Email using JSP</h1>
</center>
<p align="center">
<% 
out.println("Result: " + result + "\n");
%>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

PS. I use mail.jar and activation.jar in the class path. I will be appreciate your helps.

Here is the error messages that I have got:

```
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /mail.jsp      
 at line 37

 34:   // Now set the actual message
 35:   message.setText("This is actual message");
 36:   // Send message
 37:   Transport.send(message);
 38:   result = "Sent message successfully....";
 39: 
 40: %>


 Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.ja 
 va:510)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:401)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
com.ish.system.runtime.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilt     er.java:67)
 root cause

 javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to                       
 SMTP      host: mail.gmx.com, port: 25;
 nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.jav     a:862)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:     791)
org.apache.jsp.mail_jsp._jspService(mail_jsp.java:124)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
com.ish.system.runtime.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilt     er.java:67)
 root cause

 javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.gmx.com, port: 25;
   nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1282)
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
org.apache.jsp.mail_jsp._jspService(mail_jsp.java:98)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
com.ish.system.runtime.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilt     er.java:67)
 root cause

 java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:232)
com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189)
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1250)
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
org.apache.jsp.mail_jsp._jspService(mail_jsp.java:98)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
com.ish.system.runtime.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilt     er.java:67)
```

Comment: Please read - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.gmx.com, port: 25;  
> nested exception is: 
> java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
> ```

This is a rather low level problem. The operating system platform-specified user who is executing the current Java runtime environment is not allowed to open a network connection to the given host.

This can have many possible causes, depending on the rights of the user, the degree of higher-level control on it, the Firewall settings, the operating system used, etcetera. At least, the problem is not in your Java code *(disclaimer: I haven't read it, the whole exception is already the answer at its own, so you may still have some unrelated mistakes in your Java code)*.

I'll mention some common causes to that you understand where you should look for the solution:

- The webapplication is deployed to a 3rd party host which doesn't allow your webapplication to connect any hosts other than the 3rd party host itself. Solution: upgrade account so that you can use host's own mail server (or maybe you already have it without the need to upgrade), or migrate to another host.
- The operating system platform-specific non-admin user account is not allowed to make any network connections. The admin account must change the user's account settings accordingly.
- The operating system platform has a Firewall installed with too restrictive configuration. Try disabling the Firewall altogether and retest to exclude it from being suspect and then reconfigure the Firewall if necessary.